# Scraping Twitter follower data on Google Sheets using importXML

Tags: xml, twitter, google-sheets

I need to scrape social follower data for various pages and social platforms into a Google Sheet.

I've been able to implement importXML fairly easily to scrape data from Facebook, YouTube, Alexa Rank and more, but the same function doesn't seem to work for Twitter. In fact, I'm not able to scrape anything at all from Twitter using importXML.

Why? Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because their html is not properly formed - i have struggled with this for a long time - the best workaround I have found so far instead to partially use it in an apps script for importing the data and then regexing out the piece that you want - or finding the url to the json data that it loading and then use importdata to get it in the sheet.

```
=importdata("url")
```